# Is Spark/pyspark's RFormula an alternative for VectorAssembler and Indexers when given inside a pipeline?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pipeline, apache-spark-ml

I am new to Spark/pyspark and may have a misconception about RFormula object features. Its source code is hardly perceivable.

According to the demonstratory examples, when applied alone, RFormula certainly does the Linear Estimation when the `.fit()` and `.transform()` methods are called.
But when it is used unfitted inside `Pipeline()` it looks like it is just a concise way to show the dependent variable, and which pre-transformation should be done to data before applying an "ML" method (without making linear model estimates).

The question is - since RFormula belongs to pyspark's `ml.feature` module - is it possible to use it as the first stage of pipelines just to replace the unwieldy VectorAssembler() and StringIndexer()? (the last being essential to make IDs/indices for qualitative data, e.g. Iris's flower species).

When I tried to use two models with  Fischer's Iris `Iris.csv` dataset,
The first being a Pipeline of `RFormula("Series ~ . -Id")` and `DecisionTreeClassifier()`,
and the second being a Pipeline of `VectorAssembler(<input-Cols>, "features")`, `StringIndexer("Species", "indexedLabel")` and `DecisionTreeClassifier("indexedLabel", "features")`,
the results obtained in `.RowPredictions` column, which are highly dependent on the exact manipulations done,
were fully identical.
Has that happened because the RFormula *de facto* did only a column mapping here to a Decision Tree Estimator, not calculating anything?

Comment: Interesting. I just came to the same conclusion and was looking for some articles on the web!